# how to make vpn detector using laravel | ip2proxy laravel extension work on localhost but not work on server

Tags: laravel, proxy, vpn

After upload, this code gets the error on ip2proxy not found on the server.  I have already installed ip2proxy extension.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use IP2ProxyLaravel;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    public function lookup(Request $request)
    {
        $get_ip = "89.39.104.204";
        $records = IP2ProxyLaravel::get($get_ip, 'bin');  
        if ($records['isProxy']) {
            return view('proxy');
        } else {
            return view('non-proxy');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: run the command `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Thanks for your  attention, I tried this one also but it didn't work

Comment: have you tried using the complete namespace `use Ip2location\IP2ProxyLaravel\IP2ProxyLaravel;` ?

Comment: This one didn't work. thanks @N69S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using

> https://iphub.info/

alternate of ip2proxy

```
    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    $apikey = "MTg4ODk6MlNXYfd1p6M3JhhjhdjfhoaUI3dW1xNXZdfdfdkNlRMM21dfyQUVhZUpYS0c="; // My API Key

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://v2.api.iphub.info/ip/".$ip,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "x-key: ".$apikey
    ),
    ));

    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $block = 0;
    if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error :" . $err;
    } else {
    $block = $response->block;
    }

    if($block == 1){
    echo "Using VPN or Proxy.";
    }else{
    echo "Not using VPN or Proxy.";
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($response);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, did you run the command `composer require ip2location/ip2proxy-laravel` in your laravel main folder?

You should be able to see this line `"ip2location/ip2proxy-laravel": "^1.1",` in your laravel/composer.json after you run the command above.

Then, you may follow the steps in https://github.com/ip2location/ip2proxy-laravel#usage for the IP2Proxy laravel extension usage.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).